# Unwind segue unwinds too far

Tags: ios, swift

I am using some navigation controllers and my structure looks like this:

```
Top Nav ---Modal---> Middle Nav ---Model---> Bottom Nav
```

and

```
Top Nav ---Model---> Bottom Nav
```

In English, one navigation controler (`Top Nav`) presents another navigation controller modally (`Middle Nav`), which in turn presents another navigation controller modally (`Bottom Nav`). The `Button Nav` has a bar button that exits the view and performs an unwind action. The unwind action lives in `Top Nav`. `Bottom Nav` is reachable directly from both `Middle Nav` and `Top Nav`. The issue is that when I hit the bar button in `Bottom Nav` it always unwinds to `Top Nav`, even if I reached the view from `Middle Nav`. How can I debug / fix this?

My initial thought is that the navigation view unwinds to the controller that handled the unwind. Does this mean I need to copy the unwind method in both controllers?

Comment: Did you have a look at [Technical Note TN2298 – Using Unwind Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)? It explains all the gory details, in particular *"How an Unwind Segue Determines its Destination View Controller"*.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is documented in [Technical Note TN2298 – Using Unwind Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html):

> **How an Unwind Segue Determines its Destination View Controller**
>
> When an unwind segue is initiated, it must first locate the nearest
>   view controller in the navigation hierarchy which implements the
>   unwind action specified when the unwind segue was created. This view
>   controller becomes the destination of the unwind segue. If no suitable
>   view controller is found, the unwind segue is aborted.